# am i have error at this c++ code?

Tags: c++, loops

just want to get this results.

array A 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
array B 6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5

```
for(k=1; k=10; k++)
{
    if(k<10)
    {
        a[k]=k;
        j=k+5;
        b[j] = a[k];
    }
    else
    {
        a[k] = k;
        j = k-5;
        b[j] = a[k];
    }
    printf("%d %d \n",j,k);
}
```

but can not out of for-
keep looping at k=10.

Comment: using vs code, ubuntu 17.04 now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second part in the for loop is a condition which is evaluated after every loop. In your case the condition is `k=10` whose return value is 10, which when type casted to bool always returns `true`.

```
for (init; condition; iter-expression) {
    code
}
```

traslates to

```
{
   init 
   while ( condition ) { 
      code 
      iter_expression ; 
   }
}
```

The correct code would be:

```
for(k=0; k<10; k++)
{
    if(k<5)
    {
        a[k]=k+1;
        j=k+5;
        b[j] = a[k];
    }
    else
    {
        a[k] = k+1;
        j = k-5;
        b[j] = a[k];
    }
    printf("%d %d \n",j,k);
}
```